# Date format with place in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a date in the following format using javascript only.How can I get the name of timezone which I guess is ([Europe/London]) in this case?
Note: javascript only please :-)

```
2016-12-27T20:16:12.752+0000[Europe/London]
The format is: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'['VV']'
```

The Date methods like `new Date()` and `toISOString()` are available however they don't provide name of timezone .What else can be done?
Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: I dont think converting from time zone to a name of place can be done as more than one place can be in a particular timezone from north to south. Unless you do some pre standard mapping of one time zone to one place or use the users current coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

reference: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/

Comment: Note you'll need a polyfill for Intl depending on browser support required: http://caniuse.com/#search=intl